# Multi tenant Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a multi tenant site that serves two domains: "a.com" and "b.net". I want to setup Google Analytics so as to have separate information for these two domains, for example, I would like to see visitors, etc, for each tenant independently of the other.
Do I need two different keys (UA-xxxx-x), one for each tenant? What JavaScript shall I use?
I am using analytics.js.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#keyComponents

Comment: No, it doesn't. It uses ga.js, not analytics.js. I can google myself, you know. And why the downvote, may I ask?

Comment: Sorry, got that wrong. And the downvote wasn't from me.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help! :-) Existing documentation is a bit confusing, IMO.

Comment: If I were to provide an answer, I'd need to know what a multi tenant site means. English isn't my native language and I haven't come across that specific sentence before :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy is it this?

Comment: Yes. It's about having a single site host different "tenants", each with its own domain (simplified).

Comment: Ok, I think I am grasping it a bit better now. I am just pondering about scalability here. Will the application need to only work with the two domains you described, or are you going to be serving more tenants down the line?

Comment: That is irrelevant in what this question is concerned. Maybe or maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using one account with two different properties with a unique UA-ID for each website.

This way you won't clutter your properties with a.com's data and b.net's data and vice versa.

The other way to do it is to have one property with one UA ID and then create an include [full URL filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en) and then segment and/or filter on the specific domain.

Analytics.js is the way to go now a days. [Ga.js will be deprecated](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/#phase-4) in the future.

To add a new property, click down the property drop down and select "Create new property". [image: Adding new property]

You'd then need to do a if statement or something to check the domain. If a.com then post UA ID for a.com and vice versa.

Something like this (in PHP):

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', '<?php function UA() {
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='a.com' ) {echo 'UA-XXXXX-X';}
else {echo 'UA-XXXXX-X';}
} UA();
?>', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Comment: OK, but what about the script? How can I add two (or more) UA IDs? And what do you mean by "two different properties"? Thanks!